# Select top n items in a pandas groupby and calculate the mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': [0, 1, 2,3, 4,5,6,7,8,9],'Name': ['John', 'Jim', 'John','Jim', 'John','Jim','Jim','John','Jim','John']})
df
    Value   Name
0   0   John
1   1   Jim
2   2   John
3   3   Jim
4   4   John
5   5   Jim
6   6   Jim
7   7   John
8   8   Jim
9   9   John
```

I would like to select the top `n` items by `Name` and find the mean from the `Value` column.

I have tried this:

```
df['Top2Mean'] = df.groupby(['Name'])['Value'].nlargest(2).transform('mean')
```

But the following error:

> ValueError: transforms cannot produce aggregated results

My expected result is a new column called `Top2Mean` with a `8` next to `John` and `7` next to `Jim`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us calculate `mean` on `level=0`, then `map` the calculated mean value to the `Name` column to broadcast the aggregated results.

```
top2 = df.groupby('Name')['Value'].nlargest(2).mean(level=0)
df['Top2Mean'] = df['Name'].map(top2)
```

If we need to `group` on multiple columns for example `Name` and `City` then we have to take `mean` on `level=[Name, City]` and `map` the calculated mean values using `MultiIndex.map`

```
c = ['Name', 'City']
top2 = df.groupby(c)['Value'].nlargest(2).mean(level=c)
df['Top2Mean'] = df.set_index(c).index.map(top2)
```

**Alternative approach** with `groupby` and `transform` using a custom lambda function

```
df['Top2Mean'] = df.groupby('Name')['Value']\
                   .transform(lambda v: v.nlargest(2).mean())
```

---

```
   Value  Name  Top2Mean
0      0  John         8
1      1   Jim         7
2      2  John         8
3      3   Jim         7
4      4  John         8
5      5   Jim         7
6      6   Jim         7
7      7  John         8
8      8   Jim         7
9      9  John         8
```

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes i have multiple groupby columns so how would the line `df['Top2Mean'] = df['Name'].map(top2)` adjust for that?

Comment: @SOK Can you please give a small example of such scenario?

Comment: For example if the top2 calculation was: `top2 = df.groupby(['Name','City'])['Value'].nlargest(2).mean(level=0)` how would I map `df['Top2Mean']` to include `City` @Shubham Sharma

Comment: thanks so much! will try now and the alternative

Comment: the Alternative solutions works great! and in 1 line which is easy!

Comment: @SOK Glad it worked for you. happy coding!